# Can real numbers dimensions exist?

Tags: mathematical-physics

This title may not explain my question right but I could not think of any better short explanation.
My question is, if there is a possibility of a structure (or space) with the dimension $Dim = 3,5$, $Dim = 4,8...$ or any other real numbers value?
It's seems pretty obvious that there is no such thing like a $4,5$ dimensional sphere but I'm interested in a proof that no such structure can exist. 
Does a real dimensional space make any physical sense?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depends on how you define the word “dimension”. What do you have in mind?

Comment: I think of dimensions, like the euklidien space.

Comment: What you're looking for are fractal dimensions. Take a look at this video for a nice introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB9n2gHsHN4